# Secret Key not found when Django Unit Tests are executed

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, django-unittest

Whenever I'm running my Django-Tests via the `unittests.py` file in the main folder the `SECRET KEY` in `.env` is not found.
What is the correct way to set up the regular Unittests-File for a series of Django-Tests?
I wrote my `settings.py` in a way it's able to write a new key if no other key is found:

---**settings.py**---

```
try:
    print("Current key: " + os.environ['SECRET_KEY'])
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
except KeyError as kerr:
    logging.error("Can't find Secret Key in settings.py")
    path_env = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env')
    utils.generate_secret_key(path_env)
    dotenv.read_dotenv(path_env)
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

This has worked, but as on every run of the unittests another new key is created, which is not intended. So far I'm running the unittests with a default script which works fine, except for the issue with the key:

---**unittests.py**---

```
import DjangoProject.tests_client
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
loader = unittest.TestLoader()
suite.addTest(loader.loadTestsFromModule(DjangoProject.tests_client))
```

The implemented Test is not a too huge surprise:

```
from django.test import TestCase
import django
django.setup()

class TestBase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        #Stuff

    def tearDown(self):
        self.removeData()

    def test_Clienttest(self):
        #Stuff
```

The Unittests-Classes inherit as required from from `django.test.TestCase` and do what they are supposed to:

Running the Unittest-Script with these settings will result in an error as it can't find the `SECRET KEY` (I did some debugging and indeed, the key is not loaded in the environment). For some testing I disabled the lines in the `settings.py` which create a new key and immediately get the error:

```
$ python3.7 unittests.py
ERROR:root:'SECRET_KEY'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unittests.py", line 25, in <module>
    import DjangoProject.tests_client
  File "/home/djangohome/DjangoProject/tests_client.py", line 23, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 176, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Running the test via manage.py works perfectly fine too:

```
$ python3.7 manage.py test DjangoProject.tests_client
Current key: o5at!z(_()s2vbp=n4exot@gjo1==!w39uby*eju)ej#1o^lwn
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
... And everything as supposed to ...
```

But how would I have to implement the run via `manage.py` in the regular Unittests so the `SECRET KEY` is loaded correctly?